# Postgres update table using CTE with priority

Tags: postgresql

I have a **employee leave balance** table as follows

| emp_code | leave_type | yearmonth | Balance | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PL | 202205 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | SL | 202205 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | PL | 202205 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | SL | 202205 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | PL | 202205 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | SL | 202205 | 1 | 1 |

and a **Attendance Table** as follows

| emp_code | date | yearmonth | Attendance | Leave |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-05-01 | 202205 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2022-05-02 | 202205 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2022-05-03 | 202205 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | 202205 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-02 | 202205 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 | 202205 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-04 | 202205 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2022-05-01 | 202205 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 2022-05-02 | 202205 | 1 |  |

I just wanted to update the `attendance table` with the respective leave (based on the priority and availability) if the attendance field value is 0

For eg: employee 1 have 3 leave balance and 4 days absent

After the update, the records for emp_code 1 in attendance should be as follows

| emp_code | date | yearmonth | Attendance | Leave |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | 202205 | 0 | PL |
| 1 | 2022-05-02 | 202205 | 0 | PL |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 | 202205 | 0 | SL |
| 1 | 2022-05-04 | 202205 | 0 |  |

I know, we can do this through SP or function. But my company policy does not allow me to create SP or functions (I can update this via my backend code, but there are millions of records there to be updated so I am worried about the performance)

I wonder, is there any ways to achieve this in PG using CTE/Window function/any other means ?

here is a fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4952

Thanks

Comment: what tells us that 2022-05-01 and 2022-05-02 for emp_code 1 are both PL and not SL or null? Or do you just fille the 0 attendance dates based on priority & balance regardless?

Comment: @TomMac It is based on the priority and balance .. For Emp_code 1, Since PL has high priority,  2022-05-01 and 2022-05-02 will be adjusted against PL available.  2022-05-03 will be adjusted to SL and then for 2022-05-04, there will not any credit available set it as null / not updated
Hope this cleared

Comment: @TomMac question updated with a fiddle

Comment: @BijuSoman  In your fiddle, why does `emp_code = 1` have two conflicting `attendance` entries for May 1st?

Comment: @MikeOrganek sorry my bad! , Fiddle updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the last attendance record in your fiddle is in error and removed, then my approach would be:

1. Expand the leave balance for the month into rows using `generate_series()` and assign row numbers based on the priority
2. Assign row numbers to absences within a month
3. Calculate changes by left join from absences to leave records

```
with leave_rows as (
  select b.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by emp_code, yearmonth
                                order by priority) as use_order
    from emp_leave_balance b
         cross join lateral generate_series(1, b.balance, 1)
), absence_rows as (
  select a.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by emp_code, yearmonth
                                order by date) as use_order
    from attendance a
   where attendance = 0
), changes as (
  select a.emp_code, a.date, a.yearmonth, a.attendance, l.leave_type
  from absence_rows a
       left join leave_rows l
         on (l.emp_code, l.yearmonth, l.use_order) = 
               (a.emp_code, a.yearmonth, a.use_order)
)
update attendance 
   set leave = c.leave_type
  from changes c
 where (c.emp_code, c.date) = (attendance.emp_code, attendance.date)
;
```

Your updated [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4957)

Comment: Love `generate_series()` one of my favourite Postgres features